# pass a method into another method as a parameter but with parameters

Tags: c#

I've posted a similar question (and answered) previously but I've realised I still have a missing piece of the puzzle when passing a method into another method.  My question is when passing a method as a parameter how can you include parameters?  I've included an example below.

Any help much appreciated.

Many thanks,

**Service call**

```
private readonly MemberRepo _memberRepo;

public SomeService()
{
    _memberRepo = new MemberRepo();
}

public string GetMembers(int id)
{
    // This works, i.e. the RunMethod internally calls the Get method on the repo class - problem: how can I pass the id into the repo Get method?
    var result = RunMethod(_memberRepo.Get); 
    ...

    return stuff;
}

private string RunMethod(Func<int, string> methodToRun)
{
    var id = 10;  // this is a hack - how can I pass this in?
    var result = methodToRun(id);
    ..
}
```

**Repository**

```
public class MemberRepo
{
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "Member from repository";
    }
}
```

**Update**

```
private string RunMethod(Func<int, string> methodToRun)
{

    if(id.Equals(1))
    {
      // Do something
    //

    var result = methodToRun(id);
    ..
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass a second argument to the `RunMethod` method:

```
private string RunMethod(Func<int, string> methodToRun, int id)
{
    var result = methodToRun(id);
    ..
}
```

You can always make `id` have an optional input as well if needed:

```
int id= 10
```

Comment: oh right!  Silly me, I've been battlering with RunMethod(_memberRepo.Get(id))

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a lambda function that performs whatever actions you want:

```
var result = RunMethod(_ => _memberRepo.Get(10));
```

This makes the `int` part of the method signature pretty meaningless, so if you have the ability to change your `RunMethod()` signature, you can do this:

```
private string RunMethod(Func<string> methodToRun)
{
    var result = methodToRun();
    ..
}
```

then this:

```
var result = RunMethod(() => _memberRepo.Get(10));
```

**Update** if you need to be able to access the parameter within your `RunMethod()` method, then just pass it as a separate parameter as TheLethalCoder suggests:

```
private string RunMethod(Func<int, string> methodToRun, int id)
{    
    if(id.Equals(1))
    {
      // Do something
    //

    var result = methodToRun(id);
    ..
}
```

and

```
var result = RunMethod(memberRepo.Get, 10);
```

Comment: I don't recognise this syntax '_', what does this mean?

Comment: It's just a parameter name. You could change that to `parameterImNotGoingToUse` or any other valid C# identifier.